# Why do I get "Cannot find module 'stack-trace'" launching Appium Server?

Tags: android, appium

I'm using the tutorials on understanding how to install, configure and run Appium. This is what I did:

1. I installed Appiumforwindows version 0.18.0 from http://appium.io/
2. Started the Appium application
3. Now, I'm presented with the GUI, with three options on the Menu bar:

```
--Preferences
--Inspector
--Launch
```

and various other configuration options.

I'll describe what was configured:

From the Preferences, I checked the following options:

- Check for Updates
- Reset Application State After Each Session
- Pre-Launch Application

Also:

- IP Address: 127.0.0.1 (as default hostname)
- Port: 4723 (as default)
- Application Path: ..\sdk\build-tools\android-4.4.2 (the location of the APK file I'm looking to test - here, I'm using the dropbox apk)

From the Android Tab, I set up the following:

- Package
- Activity
- Launch AVD

The package and activity were obtained from the command prompt by running the below command in the location of the apk file (as described above in the "Application Path":

```
aapt dump badging xxx.apk (where xxx is filename of the dropbox apk)
```

Now, after doing all this, when attempting to Launch Appium, I get the following errors in the Output:

```
>Starting Node Server             
>ERROR: module.js:340                                 
>ERROR:   throw err;                    
>ERROR: Error: Cannot find module 'stack-trace'           
>ERROR:    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)         
>ERROR:    at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)              
>ERROR:    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)           
>ERROR:    at require (module.js:380:17)           
>ERROR:    at Object <anonymous> (..\\Appium\node_modules\winston\lib\winston\exception.js:10:18  
>ERROR:    at Module.compile(module.js:456:26)                  
>ERROR:    at Object.Module._extensions.js (module.js:474:10)        
>ERROR:    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)         
>ERROR:    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)                  
>ERROR:    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)             
>ERROR:                      
>Node Server Process Ended
```

So, it appears it cannot find the module 'stack-trace' at the various listed areas. Why not?

Doing a search for stack-trace files, resulted in three stack-trace.js files located in the following paths:

- \appium\node_modules\sandboxed-module\node_modules
- \appium\node_modules\prompt\node_modules\winston\node_modules
- \appium\node_modules\binary_cookies\node_modules\winston\node_modules

What have I missed out?

Answer (score 0):

install the module

`npm install stack-trace`